# C++ two is_union_or_class implementations

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I tried to implement `is_union_or_class`, first without `void_t` using following approach:

```
#include <type_traits>

    namespace detail {
        template <class T>
        struct is_union_or_class_helper1 : public std::false_type { };
        template <class T>
        struct is_union_or_class_helper1<char T::*> : public std::true_type { };
    }

template <class T>
struct is_union_or_class1 : public detail::is_union_or_class_helper1<T> { };
```

Then I tested it using dummy empty class and `value` member evaluated to `false`. Then I retried it using `void_t` like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class...>
using void_t = void;

    namespace detail {
        template <class T, class = void_t<T>>
        struct is_union_or_class_helper2 : public std::false_type { };
        template <class T>
        struct is_union_or_class_helper2<T, void_t<char T::*>> : public std::true_type { };
    }

template <class T>
struct is_union_or_class2 : public detail::is_union_or_class_helper2<T> { };
```

And this time it evaluated correctly to `true`. Why are results different? Both helpers are more specialized in case `char T::*` is valid expression, why only in second case helper inherits from `true_type`? Here is the test code:

```
struct dummy_type { };

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << is_union_or_class1<dummy_type>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << is_union_or_class2<dummy_type>::value << "\n";
}
```

I compiled this code and tests with MSVC 2015 compiler.

Comment: your specializations are doing different things - first one tests if the passed parameter is a type that can be seen as a pointer to a member variable and the second if one can create a type of pointer to a member (of given type) variable...

Comment: Should't first approach test whether T is a valid host for a member object?

Comment: no it tests if the type is a pointer to a member object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
is_union_or_class1<dummy_type>::value
```

`dummy_type` isn't a pointer to a data member of type char of a class `T` you want to deduce. In other terms, this specialization is discarded for `dummy_type` (let me say) *doesn't match* type `char T::*`.
Therefore the class template is chosen and that one inherits from `std::false_type`:

```
template <class T>
struct is_union_or_class_helper1 : public std::false_type { };
```

Something like this would work:

```
    template <class T, typename = T>
    struct is_union_or_class_helper1 : public std::false_type { };
    template <class T>
    struct is_union_or_class_helper1<T, decltype((char T::*){}, T{})> : public std::true_type { };
```

That is nothing more than another variation of the `void_t` idiom.
Let me rewrite it a bit:

```
    template <class T, typename = void>
    struct is_union_or_class_helper1 : public std::false_type { };
    template <class T>
    struct is_union_or_class_helper1<T, decltype((char T::*){}, void())> : public std::true_type { };
```

And that's it, one of the form of the `void_t` idiom for those that are still waiting the C++17.